# Export multiple data frames to excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dataframe, export

How can I export several dataframes (A,B,C, etc) to one excel file with a few lines?

```
    Excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter('Excel_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        A.to_excel(A,'A')
        B.to_excel(B,'B')
        C.to_excel(C,'C')
       .
       .
       .
```

thank you

Comment: Just put them in a list and call `df.to_excel` at each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Excel_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as Excel_file:
    for df, tabname in zip(list_of_dfs, list_of_sheetnames):
        df.to_excel(Excel_file, tabname)
```